# What is a "universal" unitary representation of a group?

Tags: representation-theory

That is the entire question.

For example, I have read in literature the "universal unitary representation of $F_2$ on a Hilbert space $H$". How is it defined canonically? In this case what would be the difference between a universal representation and any other representation?

Is it by any chance old terminology?

Comment: It could mean the left regular representation or something else. Out of context, it's hard to tell.